# Fragen vs fragen nach

Tags: difference

Ich *frage* dich, warum du gestern nicht gekommen bist.

Ich *frage nach* dir, warum du gestern nicht gekommen bist.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Sätzen?
Vielen Dank :)

Comment: Woher hast du die Sätze? Warum glaubst du, daß beide überhaupt etwas Sinnvolles bedeuten? Hast du sonst irgendeine Vorab-Recherche betrieben?

Comment: @chirlu Wieso die Unfreundlichkeit? Und es gibt gar keinen Kontext, wo die Sätze etwas Sinnvolles bedeuten würden? Wie kann man so was recherchieren?

Comment: @c.p.: Welche Unfreundlichkeit? Es ist Aufgabe des Fragestellers, z.B. in einem Wörterbuch _fragen_ nachzuschlagen und dann zu erläutern, inwiefern ihm das nicht weitergeholfen hat.

Comment: @chirlu Ich habe natürlich in einem Wörterbuch "fragen" und "fragen nach" nachgeschlagen. Die Bedeutung war dasselbe, deswegen möchte ich fragen. Guck mal "http://tr.pons.com/çeviri?q=fragen+&l=detr&in=&lf=tr" Vielen vielen Dank für deine "hilfreiche" Antwort. Deutsch ist nicht meine Muttersprache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Satz

> Ich frage nach Anna.

bedeutet nicht, dass ich Anna etwas frage. Es bedeutet, dass Anna abwesend ist, und dass ich eine andere Person frage was Anna macht, oder wo Anna ist. Der genaue Inhalt der Frage bleibt dabei offen. Die gestellte Frage könnte lauten:

> Sag mal Gerald, weist du wo Anna ist?
>   Ilse, kannst du mir sagen, warum Anna nicht hier ist?
>   Hallo Walter, wie geht es dir und deiner Frau Anna?

Wenn also jemand sagt:

> Ich frage *nach* dir.

Dann folgt daraus zwingend, dass *du* die Frage nicht hören kannst, weil du gar nicht anwesend bist. Folglich kann die Frage, die in indirekter Rede zitiert wird, nicht an dich gerichtet sein. Der Teil

> ..., warum du gestern nicht gekommen bist.

ergibt nach »Ich frage nach dir« schlichtweg keinen Sinn.

Comment: Dann gibt's noch das zusammengesetzte Verb *nachfragen* - "Ich habe nachgefragt, warum du gestern nicht gekommen bist"

Comment: Vielen Dank! Danke sehr. :)